# Why RedirectToAction loses the relative path of the app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

From one controller I want to take user to another page in the app so I say something like:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","ThatPage");
```

And I checked and both `ThatPageController` and `Index` do exist. 
But it takes the browser to the URL: `http://thatpage/`

What is going on?

Comment: Please post your routing configuration (including any areas and attribute routes). Also, is it a typo that you don't have a double quote before `ThatPage`, or is that your actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overload for RedirectToAction where you want to go to another controller and a method within that controller has two separate strings as parameters.

You would want to write:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

You're missing a " mark in the method signature.

Comment: oh that was just hanbd typing typo ! But thanks I found the issue, it is not a standard MVC question for SO, it is some internal in-house codes that causing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
This example when user closes a session
   public async Task<ActionResult> Logout()
        {
          return RedirectToAction("Index", "App");
        }

where APP is the controller and Index is the action where I have within the App controller
Appcontroller:

 in App controller I have this   

public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```